# TypeScript Error When Implementing Conditional Type in MessageStore Object

Tags: typescript

I'm encountering a TypeScript error while implementing a conditional type in a `MessagesStore` object. Here's the complete code setup:

```js
type Message = { id: number; text: string };

type MessagesStore = {
    queue: Array<Message>;
    read: <T extends boolean>(assertiveMode?: T) => T extends true ? Message : Message | undefined;
}

const store: MessagesStore = {
    queue: [],

    read(assertiveMode: boolean = false) {
        const message = this.queue.shift();

        if (assertiveMode && message === undefined) {
            throw new Error('The messages queue is empty');
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

However, TypeScript throws the following error:

```
Type '<T extends boolean>(assertiveMode?: boolean) => Message | undefined' is not assignable to type '<T extends boolean>(assertiveMode?: T | undefined) => T extends true ? Message : Message | undefined'.
  Type 'Message | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? Message : Message | undefined'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? Message : Message | undefined'.
```

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: What is `Message`?

Comment: @Camilo it's a simple type defined as: ```{ id: number; text: string }```

Comment: @Ikram Please try to avoid changes that make paragraphs unnecessarily verbose. Also, you inserted an inaccurate change into the code block.

Comment: Currently (as of TS5.3) you cannot safely implement a generic conditional return type; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the relevant feature request. For now, if you want such a return type, you'll need to use some sort of type loosening like `as any` or the like, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3BZw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes jcalz, this is the problem and it answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting the error on the TS Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKBLAJgFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNxTAQAewx8wtuJKUAvvQBQQ0JFgJkaeAGVgAe1oZsQqGqgBHMhG3EAgrVpIQAHjiJUEAHzDV6pUiJQTAFSitmJfPChV58gBsIJBIrAAo7dXUkRDpgXAA3CBh5fAgAfmIXSKgASih0Kyg3DwgvHy5tKHSJCzQoYnMpaAAfKDIvCAAzHgh8YX4RAGN5Ek4oTkVlLBytHQhiAG0AXQAaESiHfDCY+DjE5NSF338gkIKoLqQAvfyZqKiRseAoCklLC+AAC1x4ADo5to-vAfl1gGFcrYHupcF0oDtYrR4kkUmkoAAydGvd71dB49qdHokPp3HLQtTfWjyADupAgtIAooZFGEAOQuL7QN51BCabRVX7uChgUCsyFk9SDCVqJTAMi0EjYnnCKKDfhAA

Comment: @Camilo Because you're not using `MessagesStore` at all?

Comment: @jcalz you are right. That's odd, I thought I copy pasted the code from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, as of TypeScript 5.3, there is no compiler-verified type-safe way to return a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) to support this, but for now it's not part of the language.

The problem is currently that when you check `assertiveMode`, it can narrow the type of `assertiveMode` from `T` to `true` or `false`, but it doesn't have any effect on the generic type parameter `T` itself. That stays unchanged, and so the compiler still cannot tell if `message` is a suitable value of type  `T extends true ? Message : Message | undefined`.

It's possible that sometime soon this will be addressed; there is a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#56941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56941) which might possibly get merged at some point, and I see that dealing with these sort of generic functions is on the road map for TypeScript 5.5 at [microsoft/TypeScript#57475](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57475). So maybe your code will magically start working with no errors.

Until and unless that happens, you'll need to loosen the type checking to get your code to compile.  The easiest way to do that is by using [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to say that we don't want to try to check the return type at all:

```
const store: MessagesStore = {
  queue: [],

  read(assertiveMode: boolean = false) {
    const message = this.queue.shift();

    if (assertiveMode && message === undefined) {
      throw new Error('The messages queue is empty');
    }

    return message as any; // ‍♀️ ms/TS#33912
  }
}
```

It's unfortunate, but for right now, generic conditional return types are much more useful for function *callers* and not function *implementers*.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKBLAJgFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNxTAQAewx8wtuJKUAvvQCwAKFGhIsBMjTwAysAD2tDNlFQoARzIQdxAIK1aSEAB44iVBAB8wkRpVIiUUwBUorZiXzwoVRYoANhBIJNYAFEiIdMC4AG4QMIr4EAD8xK4AlFDo1lDunhDevlw6UKlSlmhQxBYy0AA+UGTeEABmPBD4dvyiogDGiiScUJzKELXSVvJKKjlq9lo6elAA2gC6ADR9i474kdG0sQlJKcT+QSEk821IgfAQ2VjqGlCDw8BQFFPVmMAAFrh4AA6bS6CDA+CAtrAcKZOwvDS4NpQA4PI7xRLJaAAMhxXx+GHQmBaKQ6JC6T0RrwBtEUAHdSBBGQBRIzKcIAclc-2g3yqCCW4LwvggFDAoE58OpvTEiwcEGAZFo1359SgUQ1JBAjAA9LqoIA+DcA7LuAWAJAAJkgHg-qD-YDAMDwQj6lC4AFkKjAwYUXUUXD9OnwRQw3WucAQOT+3AS3VA+A6eC6gDMiYAnABGABML1l-CAA)